# LazyRow incorrectly display the item, same thing applies into horizontal-scrollable Row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was implementing some cards for my app and I want to make it horizontal-scrollable, this is what I expect:

[image: Expected result]

And this is what I got:
[image: Result I got]

The same thing also applied when I duplicated the items manually inside a `Row()` and gave it `Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())`

This is how it looks like without `LazyRow()` and horizontal-scrollable `Row()`:
[image: The correct card display]

This is code for my item:

```
ElevatedCard {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(12.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .height(128.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .weight(1F),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = "${BuildConfig.WEATHER_ICON_URL}/$weatherIcon@4x.png",
                        contentDescription = weatherStatus,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(72.dp)
                            .offset(x = (-8).dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.offset(x = 8.dp),
                        text = "$temperature",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .weight(3F),
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "$placeName: $weatherStatus",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                Divider()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.WaterDrop, contentDescription = null)
                    Text(
                        text = "Humidity: ${Converters.humidityConverter(humidity)}"
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Cyclone, contentDescription = null)
                    Text(
                        text = "Wind Speed: $windSpeed"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated